# How can I modify a variable throughout the chain of calling of class through it's objects?

Tags: java, class, variables, inner-classes

I have 3 classes.

```
class ClientConnect(){
    URL url = new URL("http:XXX.XX.XX");
    Api api = new Api(url);
    api.checks.count();
}

class Api{
    ...
    URL url;
    Checks checks = new Checks(url);
    public Api(URL url){
        url = new URL(url+"/api");
    }
}

class Checks{
    ...
    public Checks(URL url){
        url = new URL(url+"/checks");
    }
    public void count(){
        url = new URL(url+"/count");
        System.out.println(url);
    }
}
```

I want the output of the calling of api.checks.count() to be http:XXX.XX.XX.XX/api/checks/count , but I am getting null. How can I carry forward my modified URL into the next chain of class. Yeah, I can do it in other ways too, but I want to chain all these using objects of the classes only.

The issue lies in the Api class, I just want the modified URL to be sent there while creating the object of Checks class inside.

Comment: Shouldn't the constructor of `Api` be initialising `Checks` with the instance of `URL` passed to it?

Comment: But then I can't call the count method, because api.checks will throw an error.

Comment: The basic problem is doing `Checks checks = new Checks(url);` isn't going to work, because the instance of `url` is `null` when the variable is initialised.  Instead, you need to initialise the variable inside the constructor of `Api`, using the parameter passed to the constructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify the `Api` constructor, and pass `url` to the `URL` constructor **after** you *initialize* `url` (and as pointed out by [@Jonk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5349624/jonk) in the comments, it should be `this.url`). Something like,

```
URL url;
Checks checks; // <-- url is null.
public Api(URL url){
    this.url = new URL(url+"/api");
    checks = new Checks(this.url); // <-- now url is initialized.
}
```

Comment: should that not be `this.url`, otherwise you're re-initialising the parameter